# Python does not select the right part of a function with if clauses

Tags: python, function

I am new in Python and I am facing a kind of silly problem since already a while. I have a simple function that calculates the self load of an object.

In case the object is of types 'la' the input requests two thickness of this object. I was thinking that the function has to make a vector for each input.

E.g. number of layers =2
     the result is a vector of two elements with a thickness chosen by the 
     user.
     thicknesses =[4 6]

The problem is that Python does not select the right operation to do with the function and it returns the the output of another part of this function. Python returns the value of self_load when types !='la'. On top of that Python does not consider another parameter of the if clauses number_edges.
Why?

Here below you can find the function and the main program with already pre selected the right input values. 
Is anybody can help me?

```
#    FUNCTION
class load: 

    def __init__(self, thicknesses, width, height, thick, types, number_edges, inclination=90, density=2500):
        self.width = width 
        self.height = height
        self.thick = thick
        self.types = types
        self.number_edges = number_edges
        self.density = density

        self.thicknesses = thicknesses

        self.inclination = inclination

        self.a = min(self.width, self.height)
        self.b = max(self.width, self.height)



    def self_load(self, gravity=9.81):
        if self.types == 'la': 
            for i in self.thicknesses:
                if self.number_edges == 'four': 
                    G = np.array(self.density * self.thicknesses * gravity * math.cos(math.radians(self.inclination)) / 1000)  # Self load in kN/m^2
                   self.self_load = G
                   # print(self.self_load)
                else : 
                    G = np.array(self.a * self.density * self.thicknesses * gravity * math.cos(math.radians(self.inclination)) / 1000)  # Self load in kN/m
                   self.self_load = G
                 #  print(self.self_load)                      
        else :            
            if self.number_edges == 'four': 
                G = self.density * self.thick * gravity * math.cos(math.radians(self.inclination)) / 1000  # Self load in kN/m^2
                self.self_load = G
                #print(self.self_load)
            else : 
                G = self.a * self.density * self.thick * gravity * math.cos(math.radians(self.inclination)) / 1000  # Self load in kN/m
                self.self_load = G
                print(self.self_load)


#     MAIN

    import function_try

"""
                   INPUT           
"""

    width = 0.66        
    height = 2.2        
    thick = 0.006      
    inclination = 45                  
    number_edges = 'four'                        
    types = 'la' 


    if types == 'la':
        n_layers = 2               # Enter number of layers
        thicknesses = []         # Create a vector
        for i in range(0, n_layers):    # Set up loop to run n times
            number = int(input('Enter the thickness: ')) 
            thicknesses.append(number)        # append to our_list
    else:
    thicknesses = 0      

    test = function_try.load(thicknesses, width, height, thick, number_edges, types, inclination)

    test.self_load()
    print('Self load is:', test.self_load)
```

Comment: A) `thicknesses = 0` should be `thicknesses = [0]` B) `load()` takes a lot of arguments, convert from just positional calls to named args, even if they are just `thicknesses=thicknesses`. This will help you avoid bugs from passing args out of order, since named args will get sorted out by name. C) your indentation is not consistent, it is important to clean this up when using Python

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot the naswer but it does not solve this problem.

Comment: If the Python `if` statement doesn't work as you expect, then I'm afraid you need to accept that it does in fact work, and your expectations are off. (If it didn't work, someone would have found out already.) Your class defines a method called `self_load()` but that method then *overwrites its own definition* with a `numpy` array. It's not at all clear why your code is doing that.

Comment: Hi, you give me a good idea, at least now I know where is the problem. I tried and I went by step by step. It seems that I have to built up another structure in python for te input.